# Finite state Markov Chain always has long-term stationary distribution?$\pi = \pi P$Always exists?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am wondering giving a finite state Markov Chain with transition probability matrix P. Is there always a probability distribution $\pi$ such that $\pi = \pi P$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there always exists such a stationary distribution.  The Perron-Frobenius theorem guarantees that such a probability distribution exists.  Moreover, if there is some $N$ so that $P^N$ has all positive entries, then $\mu P^n \to \pi$ for all $\mu$.

Comment: $\mu$ here is any initial distribution?

Comment: Could you tell me how to apply Perron-Frobenius theorem in our question?